# java action to access kerberos Hive(SSL enabled)

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, oozie

I have been trying to access Hive(Kerberos and SSL enabled) server from java action.
I need to perform some Hive actions like accessing Hive database and tables, working with hive partitions etc.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {

        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authorization", "true");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","C:\\krb\\jaas.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug","true");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
        String principalConfig = System.getProperty("kerberosPrincipal", "hive/cdlk-tars-control@ABC.COM");
        String keytab = System.getProperty("kerberosKeytab", "C:\\krb\\hive.keytab");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principalConfig, keytab);
        final UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser();
        System.out.println("Login as: " + ugi.getUserName());
        HiveConf hiveConf=new HiveConf();
        hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, args[0]);
        Hive hive = Hive.get(hiveConf);
    hive.getConf().setIntVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTORE_CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT, METASTORE_CLIENT_TIMEOUT);
    List<String> database=hive.getAllDatabases();
    //database.forEach(x->System.out.println(x));
}
```

Able to login, but unable to fetch Hive with metastore.

```
Login as: hive/cdlk-tars-control@ABC.COM
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:294)
        at com.cdlk.util.hive.HiveTest.main(HiveTest.java:36)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:4108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:237)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_all_functions(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3727)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_all_functions(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getAllFunctions(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2628)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:154)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getAllFunctions(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2562)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getAllFunctions(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:4105)
        ... 7 more
```

jass configuration

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   useTicketCache=false
   principal="hive/cdlk-tars-control@ABC.COM"
   doNotPrompt=true
   keyTab="C:\krb\hive.keytab"
   debug=false;
};
```

Please suggest the way to access Hive from java

Comment: Did you read the Oozie docs about **`hcat` credentials** (to hit the Metastore directly) and **`hive2` credentials** (to hit HiveServer2 via JDBC)?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: Check if these help.
JDBC Client Sample Code from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients
http://appcrawler.com/wordpress/2015/06/18/examples-of-connecting-to-kerberos-hive-in-jdbc/

Comment: I am able to resolve this by adding core-site.xml and hive-site.xml to the resources of executing jar. There are some other properties requires for Kerberos connection, Just providing hive metastore URL is not enough for the connection.

Comment: When running the same java action in oozie HCat Credentials are required as pointed out by  @SamsonScharfrichter